# What's the next image 2?

Tags: visual

Can you help me with this one:

[image: puzzle]

It is from a local IQ test from the schools in Vratsa, Bulgaria.

Comment: might be C (it looking like mixing of all)

Comment: It looks online to me, do you have a URL?

Comment: Sorry. It is a screenshot from internal test. I don't know if it is in the web.

Comment: I don't think there is a clear-cut answer (the existing answers somehow anecdotically proof this). Probably the main point of interest of the proctor is how you unfold your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Answer I get is

> "C".

The logic:

> Considering only the sides that have dots count the number of different sides for each example (consider both number and position of dots). Example 1 has 3 different sides. Example 2 has 2 different sides. Example 3 has 2 different sides. Example 4 has 3 different sides. Example 5 has no dots. Now the number of different patterns on TOP of each example will be the same as the number of different sides for each example.

Comment: Appreciated, however, I do not fully buy this explanation. Why is the no-dot pattern in example 3 counted as nothing (no additional color on top) and as 1-color pattern in example 5? Following the logic of example 3, there should be no color on top of example 5.

Comment: Yes, I should not have used the word "unique".  I have replaced it with "different".  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the update, but why has example 3 not three different sides?

Comment: Because my explanation begins with "Considering only the sides that have dots"...

Comment: So, example 5 has no dots and therefore should have no color (white?) on top?

Comment: Although this works it does involve ignoring the 5th image of the sequence entirely.

Comment: Example 5 has the null set or zero number of different sides and the null set or zero number of different tops.   By definition of "different" there must be at least 2 sides (or tops) that are different from each other in order to have 1 different.  If you don't have at least 1 different you must have none different as in Example 5 for both sides and top.

Comment: I still think the 3rd side of example 3 is treated differently - just to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

I get:

> A

because:

> The total number of dots alternates even, odd, even, odd, even, so that the answer must be A or E(=1+21+1). We have two tops with three colours, two tops with two colours and one top with one colour. Hence A.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

> C

Reasoning:

> The pattern of the dots above is 1) odd, odd, even 2) odd, odd, odd, 3) odd, odd, even, 4) even, even, odd, 5) even, even, even. The last  two conform to the first two, but with even replacing odd and odd replacing even. Pattern dictates that in order to be consistent the next in the series would be 6) even, even, odd. The only choice that conforms to the pattern is C.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is:

> **E**

Reasoning:

> Count the number of separate contiguous areas on the top (1st = 4, 2nd = 2 etc). The left and middle sides both have the opposite parity to that. And the  parity of the right side alternates even, odd, even, odd, even.

So, we want the option with

> left and middle sides of opposite parity to the top, with the right being the next in the sequence, namely odd. The only option that fits is **E**, which has 6 areas on the top, and odd numbers on all the sides.